# unable to achieve desired effect using CSS3

Tags: html, css, animation

I am new to the world of CSS3 and I've been trying to create a flying twitter bird effect using CSS3 but I am unable to achieve the complete thing which I want. I want to create a few top-down-left-right motion transitions for which I've created 3 .gifs in which the bird is flapping its' wings. Here's the effect which I've created, using CSS3, in which I have just used one of the three images.

[Example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/T5Rgu/7/)

```
<a target="_blank" href="javascript:void(0)" id="bird"></a>
```

```css
#bird {
     background-image: url(http://allwebutilities.com/pnc/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/bird.gif);
     width: 64px;
     height: 62px;
     top: 0px;
     left: 0px;
     position: absolute;
}

#bird
{
     animation:myfirst 10s;
     -webkit-animation:myfirst 10s; /* Safari and Chrome */
     animation-delay:5s;
     -webkit-animation-delay:5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
}

@keyframes myfirst
{
     0%   {left:0px; top:0px;}
     25% {left:302px; top:95px;}
     50% {left:-5px; top:214px;}
     100% {left:0px; top:0px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes myfirst /* Safari and Chrome */
{
     0%   {left:0px; top:0px;}
     25% {left:302px; top:95px;}
     50% {left:-5px; top:214px;}
     100% {left:0px; top:0px;}
}
```

Now when I am trying to use all the three images inside the CSS3 animation then the problem which I am facing is that the animation, which I had originally added to the .gif images using Photoshop, stops working. Here's the link of this example:

[Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/T5Rgu/11/)

```
<a target="_blank" href="javascript:void(0)" id="bird"></a>
```

```css
#bird {
     background-image: url(http://allwebutilities.com/pnc/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/bird.gif);
     width: 64px;
     height: 62px;
     top: 0px;
     left: 0px;
     position: absolute;
}

#bird
{
     animation:myfirst 10s;
     -webkit-animation:myfirst 10s; /* Safari and Chrome */
     animation-delay:5s;
     -webkit-animation-delay:5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
}

@keyframes myfirst
{
     0%   {left:0px; top:0px;}
     25% {width: 76px; height: 55px; background-image: url(http://allwebutilities.com/pnc/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/bird2.gif); left:302px; top:95px;}
     50% {width: 76px; height: 55px; background-image: url(http://allwebutilities.com/pnc/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/bird3.gif); left:-5px; top:214px;}
     100% {left:0px; top:0px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes myfirst /* Safari and Chrome */
{
     0%   {left:0px; top:0px;}
     25% {width: 76px; height: 55px; background-image: url(http://allwebutilities.com/pnc/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/bird2.gif); left:302px; top:95px;}
     50% {width: 76px; height: 55px; background-image: url(http://allwebutilities.com/pnc/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/bird3.gif); left:-5px; top:214px;}
     100% {left:0px; top:0px;}
}
```

Apart from this, I was wondering if there's any way to add a delay between two transitions? Like using `animation-delay:5s;`, I was able to add a 5s delay between the the start and the animation at  25% so, similarly, is there any way to add a 5s delay between the animation at 25% and the animation at 50% and same thing for the animation at 50% and the animation at 100%?

Other than this, here are the links to the 3 images which i'd like to use in this animation:

[Bird Image 1 http://allwebutilities.com/pnc/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/bird.gif](http://allwebutilities.com/pnc/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/bird.gif)

[Bird Image 2 http://allwebutilities.com/pnc/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/bird2.gif](http://allwebutilities.com/pnc/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/bird2.gif)

[Bird Image 3 http://allwebutilities.com/pnc/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/bird3.gif](http://allwebutilities.com/pnc/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/bird3.gif)

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question here :

[Changing Background Image with CSS3 Animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318462/changing-background-image-with-css3-animations)

However on Chrome the background image does change but the wings don't flap while the CSS animation runs.

You could try using a sprite to combine the images and then change the background-position.