# How to animate background image src with css3?

Tags: jquery, css, animation

The background-image cannot be animated with keyframes like below:

```
@keyframes kick{
    0%{background-image: url(images/img-man-1.png);}
    25%{background-image: url(images/img-man-2.png);}
    50%{background-image: url(images/img-man-3.png);}
    75%{background-image: url(images/img-man-4.png);}
    100%{background-image: url(images/img-man-5.png);}
}
.img-man{
    animation: kick 1.2s;
    animation-play-state: running;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

So, is there any method with css3. If it's impossible to do with css3 jquery is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With javaScript:

```
var frames = 3;
var img = document.getElementsByClassName('img-man')[0];
var frame = 0;
var animation = setInterval(function() { 
    if (frame == frames) { clearInterval(animation); return; }
    img.style.background = 'url(images/img-man-'+ frame++ + '.png)';
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 1):

I do believe [this](http://davidwalsh.name/background-animation-css) is what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm changing the src of background-image!

Comment: Check this out then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318462/changing-background-image-with-css3-animations

Answer (score 0):

You can get this effect by using css3 animation and keyframes. Check out this [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Qieyna/3w7Ud/).

```
.img-man
 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  animation: kick 10s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: kick 10s infinite;
  background-size:200px 200px;
 }
```

Also, remove animation-play-state: running; on your code since "running" is the default value
[see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-play-state) .

Good Luck!!.