# CSS 3 Animation is working in Chrome, not in FF and IE

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I got a background-image Animation which works in Chrome, but doesn't in Firefox and IE. Do you know why?

My CSS looks like

```
#banner {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-color: #666;
    background-image: url("../images/banner-1.jpg");
    background-position: top center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    animation-name: banner;
    animation-duration: 15s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-name: banner; 
    -webkit-animation-duration: 20s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-name: banner;
    -moz-animation-duration: 20s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes banner {
    0%  { background-image: url(../images/banner-1.jpg); }
    33% { background-image: url(../images/banner-2.jpg); }
    60% { background-image: url(../images/banner-2.jpg); }
    93% { background-image: url(../images/banner-3.jpg); }
}
@-moz-keyframes banner {
    0%  { background-image: url(../images/banner-1.jpg); }
    33% { background-image: url(../images/banner-2.jpg); }
    60% { background-image: url(../images/banner-2.jpg); }
    93% { background-image: url(../images/banner-3.jpg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes banner {
    0%  { background-image: url("../images/banner-1.jpg"); }
    33% { background-image: url("../images/banner-2.jpg"); }
    60% { background-image: url("../images/banner-2.jpg"); }
    93% { background-image: url("../images/banner-3.jpg"); }
}
```

The HTML Part is a simple Some Content

Comment: Why is the animation timing for some browsers different from the others?

Comment: little mistake, thanks. But that doesn't solve the problem :(

Comment: because it's working only in chrome, more answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318462/changing-background-image-with-css3-animations

Comment: @user123321 When you see something that essentially asks the same thing, feel free to flag it as being a duplicate. Click on the "Close" link under the question to do that.

Answer (score 3):

You can see in the [mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties) that the propertie background image is not an animatable propertie