# CSS animations don't work in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have an HTML/CSS webpage. This pages background change pictures continuously. It works in Chrome, but not in Internet Explorer — background image stays the same. I would like to point out that it will not display for you properly because the images are not included.

**HTML/CSS:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<title>Macht IT Solutions</title>
<head>
    <style>
        #body1 {
            position: relative;
            background-Color: white;
            font-color: white;
            width: 1000px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            z-index: -1;
        }

        #body2 {

            position: absolute;
            top: 140px;
            font-color: white;
            width: 1000px;
            height: 1000px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            z-index: 0;
        }

        #background {
            opacity: 0.8;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            background-image: url("back.jpg");
            font-color: white;
            width: 1000px;
            height: 1000px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            z-index: 1;
            -webkit-animation-name: bodyback;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 30s;
            -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
            animation-name: bodyback;
            animation-duration: 30s;
            animation-delay: 5s;
            -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
            animation-iteration-count: infinite;
            animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
            animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        }

        #logo {
            border: 1px solid black;
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
            padding: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
            background-image: url("networking.jpg");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center;
            height: 130px;
        }

        #about {
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            color: black;
            border: 1px solid blue;
            background-color: white;
            border-radius: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
            padding: 4px;
            width: 500px;
            z-index: 2;
        }

        #aboutmetext {
            position: absolute;
            top: 100px;
            background-color: white;
            color: black;
            float: left;
            width: 500px;
            border: 1px solid blue;
            padding: 4px;
            border-radius: 5px 30px 20px 20px;
            z-index: 2;
        }

        #video {
            position: absolute;
            top: 30px;
            left: 550px;
            border: 1px solid blue;
            background-color: white;
            float: right;
            overflow: hidden;
            border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
            height: 360px;
            z-index: 2;
        }

        #serv {
            position: absolute;
            top: 400px;
            float: left;
            width: 500px;
            border: 1px solid blue;
            padding: 4px;
            border-radius: 5px 30px 20px 20px;
            color: black;
            background-color: white;
            z-index: 2;
        }

        #services {
            position: absolute;
            top: 300px;
            font-color: black;
            float: left;
            height: 30px;
            border: 1px solid blue;
            padding: 4px;
            background-color: white;
            border-radius: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
            color: black;
            width: 500px;
            z-index: 2;
        }

        #contactus {
            position: absolute;
            top: 550px;
            float: left;
            height: 30px;
            border: 1px solid blue;
            padding: 4px;
            background-color: white;
            border-radius: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
            color: black;
            z-index: 2;
        }

        #contact {
            position: absolute;
            top: 650px;
            float: left;
            width: 500px;
            border: 1px solid blue;
            padding: 4px;
            border-radius: 5px 30px 20px 20px;
            color: black;
            background-color: white;
            z-index: 2;
        }

        @KeyFrames bodyback {
            0% {
                background-image: url("back.jpg");
            }
            25% {
                background-image: url("net1.jpg");
            }
            50% {
                background-image: url("net2.jpg");
            }
            100% {
                background-image: url("net3.jpg");
            }
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes bodyback {
            0% {
                background-image: url("back.jpg");
            }
            25% {
                background-image: url("net1.jpg");
            }
            50% {
                background-image: url("net2.jpg");
            }
            100% {
                background-image: url("net3.jpg");
            }
        }

        @KeyFrames {
        }

        @KeyFrames {
        }

        @KeyFrames {
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body id="body1">
<div id="logo" style="font-size:30px">
    <img src="machtlogo1.png" height="100" width="100"> Macht IT Solutions
</div>
<div id="body2">
    <div id="background"></div>
    <h1 id="about">About us</h1>

    <div>
        <p id="aboutmetext">
            <font>
            </font>
        </p>

        <div id="video">
            <p align="center">
                <font color="black">
                    <b>
                        What is the Internet?
                    </b>
                </font>
            </p>
            <iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Jj6EHgSsx_U?autoplay=0">
            </iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1 id="services"><font color="black">Services</font></h1>
    </div>
    <div id="serv">
        <p>
            <font color="black">
                inquiry.
            </font>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1 id="contactus"><font color="black">Contact us</font></h1>
    </div>
    <div id="contact">
        <p>
            <font color="black">
            </font>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What version of IE?  Keyframes are only supported in IE10+.

Comment: I am using version 11 of internet explorer.

Comment: Keyframes don't work with background images. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318462/changing-background-image-with-css3-animations

Comment: Then why does it work in chrome?

Comment: Add working code snippet on http://jsfiddle.net please.

Comment: [Please don't use `<font>` tags, they are obsolete and horrible to maintain.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font)

Answer (score 1):

The `background-image` property is not animatable, according to the [CSS Transitions](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-css) specification.

You should not expect this to work in any browser at the time of this writing. This may change in the future though as implementations are experimented with, and standards bodies continue to advance support for new and creative features.

If you want to swap out background images in the interim, you should do so with script, or by animating the position/size of individual background images on a single element, rather than attempting to animate the background itself.

Answer (score -2):

You are using `-webkit-animation-name` , which is only supported in Google Chrome.

Try using `-ms-animation-name`.

Comment: Since 10, Internet Explorer has supported `animation-name` unprefixed.