# Fade in on load after 5 seconds from 1st background image to 2nd background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an background image of a building (taken many many years ago). After 5 seconds I would like to fade in a second background image of the same building (up to date picture). Keeping the second background picture until the page is reloaded. Is this possible with CSS, javascript, and jquery and the lazyload plugin?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Now what? Do you want a code example?

Comment: you could do it with css alone, javascript alone - jQueery bloat is up to you, if you're already using jQueery, then no problem, but don't bloat your page with jQueery for something this simple

Comment: does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318462/changing-background-image-with-css3-animations

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make it done without JavaScript.

CSS looks like:

```
body {
    background: url('path_to_your_background_image_1');
    animation: change_background 1s ease-out 5s 1 forwards;
}

@keyframes change_background {
    to {
        background-image: url('path_to_your_background_image_2');
    }
}
```

Here's an example http://jsfiddle.net/u9jw7k5q/1/

Comment: works in chrome, doesn't work in firefox, internet exploder and other browsers not tested

Comment: @JaromandaX you should add -webkit-, -moz-, and -o- prefixes. But keep in mind this is for modern browsers. If you want support old browsers, then you want to use JavaScript.

Comment: it DOESN'T work in firefox, which DOESN'T need -moz- prefix for animations

Answer (score 0):

Here is the JS + CSS solution to this. This might help you.(tested in Chrome)

```js
var timer;

function swapImage() {
  var slide = document.getElementById('slide');
  slide.className = "fade-in";
  slide.src = "http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3cert.gif";
  clearTimeout(timer);
}
timer = setTimeout("swapImage()", 5000);
```

```css
@keyframes fadeIn {
to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.fade-in {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadeIn .5s ease-in 1 forwards;
}
```

```html
<img height="200" id="slide" src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5.gif" width="400" />
```