# Why there is fading effect when using css3 animation to change a background image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I use CSS3 animation to change a background infinitely between two images, the images will have a fading effect even if I use steps(2):
http://jsfiddle.net/exdestroyer/hmb2m8ty/`

```
body{
        background: purple;
    }
        .rabbit{

            width: 130px; 
            height: 224px;
            background-size: 100%;
            animation: jump 2s infinite steps(2);
        }
        @keyframes jump{
            from{
                background: url(http://segmentfault.com/img/bVp56q);background-size: 100%;
            }
            to{
                background: url(http://segmentfault.com/img/bVp56r);background-size: 100%;
            }
        }`
```

So how to fix the problem and remove the effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is this happening ?

When you set an animation where the initial keyframe is one image, and the final one is another, only those keyframes have a single image. All the intermediate stages have a varying degree of the one, mixed with the other.

Setting step(2) makes the animation to use only 2 of these intermediate values. One will be a solid image . But the other will have 50% of one and 50% of the other.

If you want an animation like this, using only 2 values, you need to set a radical change in the middle of the keyframes

```css
body{
 background: purple;
}
.rabbit{
 width: 130px; 
 height: 224px;
 background-size: 100%;
 animation: jump 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes jump{
 0%, 49.9% {
  background: url(http://segmentfault.com/img/bVp56q);background-size: 100%;
 }
 50%, 100% {
   background: url(http://segmentfault.com/img/bVp56r);background-size: 100%;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="rabbit"></div>
```

Besides that, note that support for animating a background image change is still weak

Answer (score 0):

I think there is two way you can fix it leo.

First Use transition in your animation like that:

```
div {
    transition: <property> <duration> <timing-function> <delay>;
}
```

Second Use a image with rotation transition instead of two image in your keyframe.

Comment: I think transition is not a good way because I need it repeats infinitely and auto starts the effect when the page loads

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be animating `background-image` via CSS. It's not in the CSS spec, and it doesn't work in non-Webkit browsers. You're probably testing it with Chrome, but if you test with Firefox, Edge etc, you'll see there is no background showing on the screen.

Comment: So the best way is using JavaScript?

Comment: Yeah, using Javascript is a good possibility. If you don't want to use it, there is an workaround [described here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318462/changing-background-image-with-css3-animations).