# change image source with delay on mouseover and mouseout

Tags: jquery

In my website I am using jQuery to change image.
I have created jQuery to do so, Now i need to do is add smooth delay on `mouseover` and `mouseout`.

I know it Could be done with `setTimeout()` but confused how to get it done.

[My Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0u0hw7L9/2/)

[For Reference](http://jsfiddle.net/p4b7P/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0u0hw7L9/8/)

use `$(".as-panel[data-index='0']")` instead of `$(this)`

Comment: If you want don't want to use $(".as-panel[data-index='0']"), you can create a reference to it like this var this = $(".as-panel[data-index='0']"); before the setTimeout function

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using keyframe , and change background image

look to this:

[Changing Background Image with CSS3 Animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318462/changing-background-image-with-css3-animations)

Comment: In my case I am using wordpress plugin and it is really lengthy process to do so... I have to make changes in the plugin. Is it possible to do it with jquery please?

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this

    $(".as-panel[data-index='0']").mouseover(function() {
    $( "span" ).text( "That was index #");
    pausecomp(500);
    $(this).find("img").attr('src','http://www.kerry-beaches.com/images/contact-me-facebook-thumbnail.jpeg');


    });

    function pausecomp(millis)
    {
        var date = new Date();
        var curDate = null;
        do { curDate = new Date(); }
        while(curDate-date < millis);
    }


    $(".as-panel[data-index='0']").mouseout(function() {
      // `this` is the DOM element that was clicked
                $( "span" ).text( "That wasindex #");
        pausecomp(500);     
     $(this).find("img").attr('src','http://blog.room34.com/wp-content/uploads/underdog/logo.thumbnail.png');


    });
    //http://www.kerry-beaches.com/images/contact-me-facebook-thumbnail.jpeg
```

Comment: Its making my functionality of image slow.