# How do I achieve this effect and what is wrong with my JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, background-image, setinterval, effects

I am trying to achieve this background effect, which changes the similar backgrounds and the result is glitchy, old TV like effect, which can be seen on [this page](https://philcasabon.com/).

In css file I have: `noise-bck--1`,`noise-bck--2`,`noise-bck--3` which have different backgrounds, and in JavaScript I tried to loop over them with `setInterval` but something is wrong.

The images from the effect are available on these links, please download them:

[bg1.png](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_TUyMZvjkjVZW8zVDUwZ1dkSVE)

[bg2.png](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_TUyMZvjkjVOUhLR0hLZEJEaHc)

[bg3.png](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_TUyMZvjkjVbnB4YjA2Wkx5eGM)

Here is my snippet:

```js
(function() {
  var frontBck = document.querySelector('.noise-bck');
  var count = 0;
  var i;
  i = setInterval(update, 100);

  function update() {
    frontBck.classList.remove('noise-bck--1');
    frontBck.classList.remove('noise-bck--2');
    frontBck.classList.remove('noise-bck--3');
    count++;
    frontBck.classList.add('noise-bck--' + count);
    if (count == 4) {
      count = 1;
    }


  }

}());
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
}
.noise-bck {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.noise-bck--1 {
  background-image: url('bg1.png');
}
.noise-bck--2 {
  background-image: url('bg2.png');
}
.noise-bck--3 {
  background-image: url('bg3.png');
}
```

```html
<div class="noise-bck"></div>
```

Comment: When count reaches 4 you need to set it back to 1

Comment: `function update() {
    frontBck.classList.remove('noise-bck--'+count);
    count++;
    if (count>3) count=1;
    frontBck.classList.add('noise-bck--' + count);
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your snippet the query selector is looking for a tag named `noice-bck`

```
var frontBck = document.querySelector('noice-bck');
```

Try changing the query selector to look for an element with the class `noice-bck` instead.

```
var frontBck = document.querySelector('.noice-bck');
```

And.. you counter increases indefinitely..

Comment: How do you know that was not intentional? Could be like street for "nice back"... nice.. noice... noice back... noice-bck   ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should use CSS3 animations instead of javascript timers. See an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318462/changing-background-image-with-css3-animations).

Comment: Some more [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) on css3 animations  for you

Comment: From your first link: `Background image isn't a property that can be animated - you can't tween the property.`

Comment: Its not about animating images, emphasis is on looping them.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistakes are structural. `document.querySelector('noise-bck')` selects the first `<noise-bck>` element, which is not a valid element. You may have meant to select the element with `class="noise-bck"` (via `document.querySelector('.noise-bck')`. It is also better to write the `setInterval()` function separately rather than inside a variable. Here is the corrected code (notice that I have used the body element rather than that you are looking for using `document.querySelector()`.

```js
(function() {
  var frontBck = document.querySelector('.noise-bck');
  var count = 0;
  setInterval(update(), 100);

  function update() {
    frontBck.classList.remove('noise-bck--1');
    frontBck.classList.remove('noise-bck--2');
    frontBck.classList.remove('noise-bck--3');
    count++;
    frontBck.classList.add('noise-bck--' + count);


  }

}());
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
}
.noise-bck {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.noise-bck--1 {
  background-image: url('bg1.png');
}
.noise-bck--2 {
  background-image: url('bg2.png');
}
.noise-bck--3 {
  background-image: url('bg3.png');
}
```

```html
<div class="noise-bck"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Andrej Tomas - Take a look [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/3tj8DpBCyDIKdDSBdcwA?p=preview), I am looping background images using CSS3 animation.

```
@-webkit-keyframes example {
0%   {background-image: url(https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png);}
25%  {background-image: url(https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/9b/a2/57/9ba25796112cad616be27e473ae1e149.jpg);}
50%  {background-image: url(https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/ce/5f/53/ce5f53437e291c48705428721406985c.jpg);}
100% {background-image: url(http://static.zikvid.com/crop/-/480/uploads/apps/games/560c672ea57e1f2dead096834d82a1db.jpg);}
}
```