# How do I add a fade transition into JS code?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to get the background image of a certain div, to change/cycle through an array of images using the following code.

It works as supposed, only thing I have no idea is how to implement a fade in/fade out transition effect when it comes to JS. I tried it in CSS, but it only affects the very first load of the first image, when the whole page is loaded.

Can you please help me implement a fade transition between images?

```
function displayNextImage() {
    x = (x === images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
    document.getElementById("slider-background").src = images[x];
}
function changeImage() {
    setInterval(displayNextImage, 5000);
}

var images = [], x = -1;
images[0] = "https://www.example.com/1.jpg";
images[1] = "https://www.example.com/2.jpg";
images[2] = "https://www.example.com/3.jpg";
```

Comment: usually you would have separate images and absolutely position them on top of each other and cycle through them and add a class to the active one to trigger a transition to fade it in whilst removing the class from the previous active which would fade it out at the same time.  The way you are doing it, you would have to fade the image out first, once the animation completes, then you would need to change the src, after that you would need to fade it back in - but this way you wouldn't have a transition between images, your image would completely disappear before the next image shows

Comment: This is also possible with [CSS background images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318462/changing-background-image-with-css3-animations)

Comment: This tutorial helps you : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-add-fade-out-effect-using-pure-javascript

Comment: `Tried in CSS, but it only affects the very first load of the first image` you probably did it wrong

Answer (score 0):

Other solution (include using opacity and preloading images):

```js
let images = [], x = 0;
images[0] = "https://via.placeholder.com/100/FF0000/FFFFFF/?text=Image_1:.*";
images[1] = "https://via.placeholder.com/100/0000FF/FFFFFF/?text=Image_2:.*";
images[2] = "https://via.placeholder.com/100/00FF00/000000/?text=Image_3:.*";
    
function displayNextImage() {
    const image = document.getElementById("slider-background");
    x = (x === images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
    
    if (!image.classList.contains('show') || !image.classList.contains('showhide')) {
        image.classList.add('hide');
    }
    
    image.classList.replace('show', 'hide');
    setTimeout(() => {
        image.src = images[x];
        setTimeout(() => {
            image.classList.replace('hide', 'show');
        }, 400);
    }, 400);
}
    
function changeImage() {
    setInterval(displayNextImage, 5000);
}
    
changeImage();
```

```css
.show {
    transition: opacity 400ms;
    opacity: 1;
}
.hide {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 400ms;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preload" as="image" href="https://via.placeholder.com/100/FF0000/FFFFFF/?text=Image_1:.*">
<link rel="preload" as="image" href="https://via.placeholder.com/100/0000FF/FFFFFF/?text=Image_2:.*">
<link rel="preload" as="image" href="https://via.placeholder.com/100/00FF00/000000/?text=Image_3:.*">
    
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/FF0000/FFFFFF/?text=Image_1:.*" alt="" id="slider-background" />
```